# Storing large amounts of data in a database

Tags: database, postgresql, home-automation

I'm currently working on a home-automation project which provides the user with the possibility to view their energy usage over a period of time. Currently we request data every 15 minutes and we are expecting around 2000 users for our first big pilot.

My boss is requesting we that we store at least half a year of data. A quick sum leads to estimates of around 35 million records. Though these records are small (around 500bytes each) I'm still wondering whether storing these in our database (Postgres) is a correct decision.

Does anyone have some good reference material and/or advise about how to deal with this amount of information?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For now, 35M records of 0.5K each means 37.5G of data.  This fits in a database for your pilot, but you should also think of the next step after the pilot.  Your boss will not be happy when the pilot will be a big success and that you will tell him that you cannot add 100.000 users to the system in the next months without redesigning everything.  Moreover, what about a new feature for VIP users to request data at each minutes...

This is a complex issue and the choice you make will restrict the evolution of your software.

For the pilot, keep it as simple as possible to get the product out as cheap as possible --> ok for a database.  But tell you boss that you cannot open the service like that and that you will have to change things before getting 10.000 new users per week.

One thing for the next release: have many data repositories: one for your user data that is updated frequently, one for you queries/statistics system, ...

You could look at [RRD](http://www.mrtg.org/rrdtool/doc/rrdcached.en.html) for your next release.

Also keep in mind the update frequency: 2000 users updating data each 15 minutes means 2.2 updates per seconds --> ok; 100.000 users updating data each 5 minutes means 333.3 updates per seconds.  I am not sure a simple database can keep up with that, and a single web service server definitely cannot.

Comment: Speed is also an hardware issue, especially storage.

Answer (score 4):

We frequently hit tables that look like this.  Obviously structure your indexes based on usage (do you read or write a lot, etc), and from the start think about table partitioning based on some high level grouping of the data.

Also, you can implement an archiving idea to keep the live table thin.  Historical records are either never touched, or reported on, both of which are no good to live tables in my opinion.

It's worth noting that we have tables around 100m records and we don't perceive there to be a performance problem.  A lot of these performance improvements can be made with little pain afterwards, so you could always start with a common-sense solution and tune only when performance is proven to be poor.

Answer (score 1):

With appropriate indexes to avoid slow queries, I wouldn't expect any decent RDBMS to struggle with that kind of dataset.  Lots of people are using PostgreSQL to handle far more data than that.

It's what databases are made for :)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I would suggest that you make a performance test - write a program that generates test entries that corresponds to the number of entries you'll see over half a year, insert them and check results to see if query times are satisfactory. If not, try indexing as suggested by other answers. It is, btw, also worth trying write performance to ensure that you can actually insert the amount of data you're generating in 15 minutes in.. 15 minutes or less.

Making a test will avoid the mother of all problems - assumptions :-)

Also think about production performance - your pilot will have 2000 users - will your production environment have 4000 users or 200000 users in a year or two?

If we're talking a really big environment, you need to think about a solution that allows you to scale out by adding more nodes instead of relying on always being able to add more CPU, disk and memory to a single machine. You can either do this in your application by keeping track on which out of multiple database machines is hosting details for a specific user, or you can use one of the Postgresql clustering methods, or you could go a completely different path - the [NoSQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL) approach, where you walk away completely from RDBMS and use systems which are built to scale horizontally.

There are a number of such systems. I only have personal experience of [Cassandra](http://cassandra.apache.org/). You have to think completely different compared to what you're used to from the RDBMS world which is something of a challenge - think more about how you want 
to access the data rather than how to store it. For your example, I think storing the data with the user-id as key and then add a column with the column name being the timestamp and the column value being your data for that timestamp would make sense. You can then ask for slices of those columns for example for graphing results in a Web UI - Cassandra has good enough response times for UI applications.

The upside of investing time in learning and using a nosql system is that when you need more space - you just add a new node. Same thing if you need more write performance, or more read performance.

Answer (score 0):

Are you not better off not keeping individual samples for the full period? You could possibly implement some sort of consolidation mechanism, which concatenates weekly/monthly samples into one record. And run said consolidation on a schedule.

You decision has to depend on the type of queries you need to be able to run on the database.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of techniques to handle this problem. you will only get performance if you touch minimum number of records. in your case you can use following techniques.

1. Try to keep old data in separate table here your can use table partitioning or can use a different kind of approach where you can store your old data in file system and can serve them directly from your application without connecting to database, this way your database will be free. I am doing this for one of my project and it already has more than 50GB of data but it is running very smoothly.
2. Try to index table columns but be careful as it will affect your insertion speed.
3. Try batch processing for your insertion or select queries. you can handle this issue very smartly here.
   Example: suppose you are getting request to insert record in any table after every 1 second then you make a mechanism where you process this request in batch of 5 record in this way you will hit your database after 5 second which is much better. Yes, you can make users to wait for 5 second to wait for their record inserted like in Gmail where you send email and it ask you to wait/processing. for select you can put your resultset periodically in file system and can serve them directly to user without touching database like most stock market data company do.
4. You can also use some ORM like Hibernate. They will use some caching techniques to boost speed of your data.

For any further query you can mail me on ranjeet1985@gmail.com